# Can't Apply Changes to Permissions Within a Folder's Enclosed Files in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

[Issue with the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQmX2.png)
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am trying to allow all enclosed Files and Folders to have full Read and write access as well as Create and delete files. Currently, it is set to Read and write and create and delete files for both the Owner and Group, but Others is set to Read-only and Access Files. I am trying to change Others to full Read and Write and Create and delete files, but every time I try and change the permissions and press "change" it doesn't actually change anything. Any idea as to how I can fix this?

[image]